# How do I make a class instance using user input?

Tags: python

I am making a text based adventure game in python. Once the game begins, I would like to create an instance of a class called "Character" which is the player's character object. I would like the user to be able to choose the race of the character they want to play. So far I have:

```
class Race:
    def __init__(self, name, passive, hp):
        self.name = name
        self.passive = passive
        self.hp = hp
```

and

```
class Lizard(Race):
    def __init__(self, name, passive, hp):
        super().__init__(name, passive, hp)
        self.name = 'Lizardman'
        self.passive = 'Regrowth'
        self.hp = 20

    def regrowth(self):
        if 0 < self.hp <= 18:
            self.hp += 2
```

and

```
def race_select():
    races = ['Lizard']

    while True:
        for i, j in enumerate(races):
            print(f"[{i + 1}]", j)

        choice = int(input('Pick a race:'))

        if choice <= len(races):
            print('You are a ', races[choice - 1])
            return races[choice - 1]
        else:
            continue
```

If I understand correctly, if I wanted the race to be a Lizard, I would still have to do

```
character = Lizard('Lizardman', 'Regrowth', 20)
```

Is there an easy way to let the user choose the race and the object to be created accordingly? Thanks

Comment: To answer both your questions, right now it sort of works but I have to finagle it to output the right thing so it only works if there is one race choice. I am just a bit confused because I was wondering if there were some way to make it so that I could just say character = Lizard() without specifying any parameters, because I already gave the parameters in the class Lizard code (aka the 'Lizardman', 'Regrowth', 20... seems a bit repetitive to have to do it twice)

Comment: As for the parameters, you can simply have an empty `__init__` for Lizard, and just pass hardcoded "Lizardman", "Regrowth", 20, .... to super().

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution would be to map a name to a class using a dictionary. As a simple example:

```
race_map = {"lizard": Lizard,
            "human": Human}  # I'm adding a theoretical other class as an example

choice = input('Pick a race:')
race_initializer = race_map.get(choice, None)  # Get the chosen class, or None if input is bad
if race_initializer is None:
    # They entered bad input that doesn't correspond to a race
else:
    new_creature = race_initializer(their_name, their_passive, their_hp)
```

`new_creature` is now the new object of the chosen class.

You may want to standardize the input using `choice.lower()` to ensure that capitalization doesn't matter when they enter their choice.

---

I changed it to allow for specifying a race by a string name instead of a number. If you wanted a number, you could keep your list, but apply the same idea. Something like:

```
race_list = races = [('Lizard', Lizard), ('human', Human)]
choice = int(input('Pick a race:'))
try:
    race_initializer = race_list[choice][1]  # 1 because the class object is the second in the tuple
    new_creature = race_initializer(their_name, their_passive, their_hp) 
except IndexError:
    # Bad input
```

I included the name in the `race_list` so that you can loop over the list and print out index->name associations for the user to pick from.

You may also want to use a more robust structure than a plain tuple to store name->initializer mappings, but it works well in simple cases.

Comment: Awesome thanks for clearing that up. Just to make sure, would the code you shared go inside of a function? Can you create an instance of a class inside of a function and you can mess around with it outside of that function?

Comment: @Schnibs This code could definitely be inside of a function. If you wanted `new_creature` outside of a function that it was created in, you could simply `return` the object from the function, or have the function as a method of a "environment" class that houses all the objects that the game uses, and `append` the `new_creature` to a list of creatures that the class maintains. It really depends on how you plan on structuring things.